# Setup Tunnel via ssh and use it's Internet for VPN clients

Tags: ssh, iptables, vpn, centos6, ssh-tunnel

I have two VPS centos 6.6 x64 with Public IP addresses example:**1.1.1.1** and **2.2.2.2**
VPS with **1.1.1.1 is a VPN server**
 I Need to connect 1.1.1.1 via ssh to 2.2.2.2
 so My **VPN clients on 1.1.1.1** can **Have 2.2.2.2** Public IP address
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the man page for ssh, it gives you a great example in there:

```
man ssh

SSH-BASED VIRTUAL PRIVATE NETWORKS
 ssh contains support for Virtual Private Network (VPN) tunnelling using the tun(4) network pseudo-device, allowing two networks to be joined securely.  The sshd_config(5) configuration option PermitTunnel controls whether the server sup-
 ports this, and at what level (layer 2 or 3 traffic).

 The following example would connect client network 10.0.50.0/24 with remote network 10.0.99.0/24 using a point-to-point connection from 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.2, provided that the SSH server running on the gateway to the remote network, at
 192.168.1.15, allows it.

 On the client:

       # ssh -f -w 0:1 192.168.1.15 true
       # ifconfig tun0 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.252
       # route add 10.0.99.0/24 10.1.1.2

 On the server:

       # ifconfig tun1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252
       # route add 10.0.50.0/24 10.1.1.1

 Client access may be more finely tuned via the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file (see below) and the PermitRootLogin server option.  The following entry would permit connections on tun(4) device 1 from user ``jane'' and on tun device 2 from
 user ``john'', if PermitRootLogin is set to ``forced-commands-only'':

   tunnel="1",command="sh /etc/netstart tun1" ssh-rsa ... jane
   tunnel="2",command="sh /etc/netstart tun2" ssh-rsa ... john

 Since an SSH-based setup entails a fair amount of overhead, it may be more suited to temporary setups, such as for wireless VPNs.  More permanent VPNs are better provided by tools such as ipsecctl(8) and isakmpd(8).
```

You would also have to setup routes to ensure that the traffic flows to the correct "interface".

If you are looking for a more permanent setup, you might consider OpenVPN or IPSec based VPNs as they are a little more suited to the job and are more adaptable.

Don't create the VPNs using the Public IP's as the only IP's in the ifconfig, you will need to specify a private network to each of the servers, for instance

Server @ 1.1.1.1 - Private tun0 IP - 10.0.100.0/28 - 10.0.100.1

Server @ 2.2.2.2 - Private tun0 IP - 10.0.200.0/28 - 10.0.200.1

Then route traffic from 10.0.100.1 -> 10.0.200.1 or the other way round respectively.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve as you can also setup an SSH tunnel to route only specific ports and specific traffic

Comment: Thanks alot , It was so helpfull, I will change it to openvpn or IPSec,I found the way by your answer.